# What is the best way to obtain pure drinking water in the U S?

Tags: water

Tap water is awful in the U S. I am looking for a way to drink pure drinking water. I researched many options

1. carbon filters is a basic option . However they do not remove fluoride
2. distilled water is not healthy
3. reverse osmosis water is not healthy

How to organize a daily supply of pure drinking water?

Comment: There is nothing unhealthy about distilled or reverse-osmosis water. They lack the minerals often found dissolved in regular water, but those can be obtained elsewhere. So obviously you're not actually looking for pure water but rather water that meets some unspecified standard you have in mind. You need to specify what that standard is to make your question answerable.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "awful"? Do you not like the taste, or do you believe it to be "not healthy" also?

Comment: Fluoride that is added to tap water is done so for good reason. It is not harmful to you.

Comment: Have well water. Have it tested for dangerous chemicals and you're good to go. City water is disgusting.

Comment: Pure doesn't mean healthy. There are more characteristics to be obsverved....water pH....conductivity...where has it been bottled(due to the sunlight exposure over plastic causing female hormones to be released on the water.)

Comment: We use an Air Water Life alkaline water ionizer with an attached fluoride filter. Water goes through the fluoride filter first and then enters the ionizer. I don't know if it is the best method, but I am happy with the results it provides.

Answer (score 4):

**Mineral water** from a glass bottle can have a good taste, is clean and does not contain fluoride (or far less than tap water).

It is **sodium** in mineral water that is most responsible for its (good) taste. Different brands contain different (small) amounts of sodium, mostly in the range 50-200 mg/liter.

You do not need to seek for "healthy minerals" (calcium, magnesium) in water because you usually get them in greater amounts from foods.

Here on [USDA](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/list?qlookup=mineral%20water&qt=&manu=&SYNCHRONIZER_URI=%2Fndb%2Fsearch%2Flist&SYNCHRONIZER_TOKEN=5afe38ca-fafc-4036-899f-edc1a6dbd770&ds=) is a list of about 100 brands of mineral waters with nutrition facts, here is [one example](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/4177?man=&lfacet=&count=&max=50&qlookup=mineral+water&offset=0&sort=default&format=Abridged&reportfmt=other&rptfrm=&ndbno=&nutrient1=&nutrient2=&nutrient3=&subset=&totCount=&measureby=&Qv=10&Q7847=8.0&Qv=1&Q7847=8.0): 330 mg Ca, 110 mg Mg, 130 mg Na per liter.

**Distilled water** contains no minerals, so it does not have any taste. Reverse osmosis water is pretty much the same.